# How to publish ASP.NET Core and locally existing database to Azure?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

I have a problem trying to publish my ASP.NET Core project.

I publish ASP.NET Core project and I see this url

[image]

What should I do to publish my database so that it works?

Comment: You want to publish database or asp.net core project? How are you publishing the project? Where do you see this URL?

Comment: like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-vs?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: And what' the issue you are facing ?

Comment: If you'd like to access on-premises database from your Azure app service, you can try to create and use a [Hybrid Connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections).

Comment: What have you tried? What database? Published from VS?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in 2 steps:

- Create a Database project: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-sql-server-database-project-with-visual-studio/
- Publish using VS: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/suthish_nair/publish-web-or-database-project-using-visual-studio-2012/